# Button with custom background and "?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, android-button, android-attributes

How to define a `Button` with custom background and the attribute 
`"?attr/selectableItemBackground"` ?

With this code the `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"` attribute is ignored, it doesn't show the touch feedback.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

---

With this other code the selectable works but I lose the background color:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Comment: You can user `ripple` drawables instead.

Comment: But I don't want to create a ripple for API>21 and another drawable for API<21. It is not posible with an attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright you have an option of `parent`

Create parent and give `background` to white color and use `selectableItemBackground` as child's background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is a good practice to add a parent layout just to get a background color for his child?

Comment: Not a good practice, but since you do not want to use `ripple` drawable, Its is an option.

Answer (score 3):

Try set

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Example main layout activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.petercarlim.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or set in parent(other layout that call this layout) of you layout:

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: what API Level?

Comment: API 25 and the minimum is 15

Comment: Here work... button with flags clickable, focusable, focusableInTouchMode, foreground and background, but my main layout don't have background or foreground. And my app theme is "default". What is your layout theme?

Comment: Edit your answer with your layout and button inside, I will try it. My AppTheme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should write a special drawable for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable_rounded_enabled" android:state_enabled="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable_rounded_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
        </selector>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This must be the most recommendable answer. Working like a charm.